# This method can't be used with an inline response mail item

Tags: vb.net, vsto, outlook-addin

I have an Outlook add-in that monitors sent items and moves specific emails to a folder. I am not sure what have changed, but when I send an email, I get this error:

```
This method can't be used with an inline response mail item.
```

[image]

[image]

Here is my code. It fails while moving the mail item (Mail.Move(TargetFolder)) when IsSentItem is true:

```
Private Sub MoveMailToFolder(ByVal TargetFolder As Outlook.Folder, ByVal Mail As Outlook.MailItem, ByVal IsSentItem As Boolean)
        Try
            If Mail.ReadReceiptRequested Then
                ''continue /keep original mail as is
            Else
                'Mail.UnRead = False
                Mail.UnRead = True
            End If

            If IsSentItem Then
                Mail.UnRead = False
                Mail.Move(TargetFolder)
            Else
                Mail.Move(TargetFolder)
                'Mail.SaveSentMessageFolder = TargetFolder
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString & " " & ex.HResult.ToString & " " & ex.GetBaseException.ToString)
        Finally
            ''
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Can you advise how this can be fixed?

Comment: Could you point out which line is the 1003 that appears on the error message?

Comment: @mcutrin   it is the **Mail.Move(TargetFolder)** in the following code:
`If IsSentItem Then
                Mail.UnRead = False
                Mail.Move(TargetFolder)
            Else`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the inline response needs to be closed first. You also need to avoid calling methods like that from inline response or `MailItem` event handlers. In the latter case, you can start a timer (use the `Timer` class from the `Forms` namespace rather than `Threading` as it fires on the main thread) and call code like yours in the timer event handler (when you are out of the `MailItem` event handler).

To close an inline response, you can try to use [Accessibility API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/windows-automation-api-portal) to simulate a click on the "Discard" button or, if using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, its [SafeExplorer](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/SafeExplorer.htm) object - it exposes `ActiveInlineResponseDiscard`  method:

```
set sExplorer = CreateObject("Redemption.SafeExplorer")
sExplorer.Item = Application.ActiveExplorer
sExplorer.ActiveInlineResponseDiscard
```